# Exception handling in ruby - Deep down or in the top layer?

Tags: ruby, exception, refactoring, dry

Here are two ways of handling exceptions

First

```
def prep_food
    get_veggies()
    get_fruits()
rescue Exception => e
    # => do some logging
    # => raise if necessary
end

def get_veggies()
    # gets veggies
end

def get_fruits()
    # gets fruits
end
```

Second

```
def prep_food
    get_veggies()
    get_fruits()
end

def get_veggies()
    # gets veggies
rescue Exception => e
    # => do some logging
    # => raise if necessary
end

def get_fruits()
    # gets fruits
rescue Exception => e
    # => do some logging
    # => raise if necessary
end
```

The first one handles exceptions in the top layer where as the second way does it deep down.
What is the difference between the two and when should a programmer choose between them?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to rescue exceptions as specific (`rescue FooException` instead `rescue Exception`) and as close as possible to the line where they might be raised (my `begin ... rescue` block are usually contain only one line).

Furthermore I rescue only from exceptions that I am able and willing to handle. If I cannot "fix" an exception, what is the point of catching it?

That said: I would choose your seconds example. If I had to handle the same type of exception in the same way, then I would consider introducing a method that takes a block and does the error handling. Something like:

```
def get_veggies
  with_foo_error_handling do
    # gets veggies
  end
end

def get_fruits
  with_foo_error_handling do
    # gets fruits
  end
end

private

def with_foo_error_handling
  begin
    yield
  rescue FooException => e
    # handle error
  end
end
```

Comment: If I cannot "fix" an exception, what is the point of catching it?
I prefer to catch specific exceptions myself. But in some cases I catch all exceptions and write those to logs and then raise it again. This here was just an example and the question wasn't directed towards catching specific exceptions instead the location of catching exceptions.

Comment: Agree: Logging and re-raising might be a valid way of handling an exception. Even ignoring might be okay in some special cases. It depends...